# How to play a sequence of images with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, web

I am trying to play a sequence of images in javascript. I have no clue how to start, since I just started to learn Javascript a few days ago. I have been trying to find help for this problem but I have had no luck.

I want to make it so:

1. User clicks a button
2. The site plays through a sequence of images one by one

This is what I have now:

http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/practice.php

When you push the button "New Letter", it shows you an image of a new letter.

I want to know how to show entire words (sequence of letters) when the user clicks the button: So it will play a sequence of image after image to make a word.

Here is an example of what I want:

http://asl.ms

I dont want the levels or speed or length of word, just being able to make a word.

Comment: It is hard to follow your question. Can you try to rephrase and make it a bit more succinct exactly what you want help with, e.g. are you looking for help in how to set up a timer that pauses between individual letters? How to generate a random word to display, or what?

Comment: I am trying to make it to where I connect the images to play sort of like a gif.

Comment: Yes, but which part of that is it you need help with? This is not a "fix my program" site. We can help you with specific issues, not just give you a solution...

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to start it

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what part you're looking for, but if it is the problem of displaying images in a loop, one by one, the secret sauce you're looking for are timers. Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach. I assume you have an `img` tag with ID `image` and an entry field with ID `text` from where I pick the word to spell:

```
function setLetter(letter) {
  var img = document.getElementById("image");
  if (letter && letter.length == 1) {
    img.src = "http://thecodingninja.com/muslim/fingerspellingimg/"+letter+"abc.jpg";
  }
  else {
    img.src = "";
  }
}

function nextLetter(word) {
  if (word.length > 0) {
    var firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
    setLetter(firstLetter);
    setTimeout(nextLetter, 1000, word.substring(1));
  }
  else {
    setLetter();
  }
}

function spellWord() {
  var word = document.getElementById("text").value;
  nextLetter(word.toUpperCase());
}
```

The `setLetter()` function will set the image for the given letter (assumes it is upper-case. A more robust implementation would check if it is a character that we already have an image for)

The `nextLetter()` function will pick out the first letter, set that in the image and then set a timer to call itself 1000ms later with the word sans the first letter.

The `spellWord()` function will pick the word from the entry field and call `nextLetter()` to set the first letter and activate the timer-based spelling of the rest of the word.

I used [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wakunimoha/1/edit?html,js,output) to test the solution.